# Horizontal Menu that will add drop down option if too long

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation

I'm build a site that needs to have horizontal menus and they all need to fit on one row, however if they add too many menu items we would like for the last item to convert to a drop-down with any menu items that didn't fit.

I don't want it to be a solution where "after the 5 menu" start a dropdown, I want the script  to know that the menu is to long and automatically create it when needed.

So if they put have a menu like

Short Link  -  Short Link  -  Short Link  -  Short Link  -  Short Link

it will display normal with no drop down, however if they go hog wild and add twenty items it will go like

Short Link  -  Short Link  -  Short Link  -  Short Link  -  Short Link  -  [Drop Down with 15 other links]

Would love for it to be a jquery solution but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can assign an event to window resize. When it hits a specific point, make the change.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < whatever) {
        //Change the menu...
        //eg. $('#menu').addClass('condensed');
    }
});
```

You could even try it with purely CSS.

```
@media only (max-width: whatever) {
    #menu {
        /* Override with new styling */
    }
}
```